# Datatool : How to pick manually some rows in a specific order

Tags: datatool

I've got a large multi-purpose database and i would like to pick several items in it (using labels) and print them in the given order, not the database order or any entry-related order.

For example, i currently use this code (found on this site, thanks to Peter Grill) :

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longdata}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{foo.dat}
Hammer001,   Hammer,    1 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , light\\
Hammer002,   Hammer,    2 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , heavy\\
Hammer003,   Hammer,    3 ,  0 , 1 , 10 , 1 , really heavy\\
Longsword001,Longsword, 1 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , one-handed \\
Longsword002,Longsword, 2 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , two-handed \\
Longsword003,Longsword, 3 , -1 , 2 , 75 , 2 , three-handed \\
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2]{%
% #1 = database to search
% #2 = list of rowIDs
\begin{enumerate}
\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{#2}{\RowID}]{#1}{%
    \RowID=RowID,%
    \Label=Label,%
    \Cost=Cost,%
    \Weight=Weight,%
    \Description=Description%
    }{%
    \item \Label ; Price=\Cost ; Weight=\Weight ; It's very \Description
}%
\end{enumerate}
}%

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb[noheader,keys={RowID,Label,Cost,Weight,PropA,PropB,PropC,Description}]{myDB}{foo.dat}

\PrintDTLTable{myDB}{Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003}
\end{document}
```

The command

```
\PrintDTLTable{myDB}{Hammer001,Hammer003,Longsword003}
```

is doing exactly what i want except that

```
\PrintDTLTable{myDB}{Hammer003,Longsword003,Hammer001}
```

would obviously produce the exact same result.

Is there any way to keep the given order ? (sorry for my poor english)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\DTLforeach` visits the rows one after another. Therefore the row order of the
data base matters:

```
\DTLforeach*[\DTLisSubString{#2}{\RowID}]{#1}{%
 % #2 = list of rowIDs
```

In the following solution I have put the data extraction in a for loop
that iterates over the given row IDs. There are many for loops, e.g.
LaTeX's `\@for`. I am using `\comma@parse` from package kvsetkeys, because
it removes leading and trailing spaces from the entries in the list.
Then the row id is compared with `\equal` to get only exact matches.

```
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\PrintDTLTable}[2]{%
  % #1 = database to search
  % #2 = list of rowIDs
  \begin{enumerate}
    \comma@parse{#2}{%
      \DTLforeach*[\equal{\comma@entry}{\RowID}]{#1}{%
        \RowID=RowID,%
        \Label=Label,%
        \Cost=Cost,%
        \Weight=Weight,%
        \Description=Description%
      }{%
        \item \Label ; Price=\Cost ; Weight=\Weight ; It's very \Description
        \dtlbreak
      }%
      \@gobble % ignore the entry argument provided by \comma@parse
    }%
  \end{enumerate}
}%
\makeatother
```

Of course the run time behaviour of this algorithm is poor.
For a data base with n entries and m selected rows is is is O(n*m). That means
O(n²) if the whole data base is output. Theoretically sorting can be done
in O(n*log(n)).

Comment: `<sup>2</sup>` works on tex.sx as well (and so does `<sub>...</sub>`).